# PHP strcmp question

Tags: php, web-crawler, strcmp

I have been writing a webcrawler program, and I am attempting to compare a previous url (for the last site visited) with a current url (the current or next site to visit). To do this I am using a `strcmp` function such as this:

```
array_push($currentsite, $source);
  if (strcmp($currentsite[2], $currentsite[3])==0){
    echo "redundancy";
    crawlWebsite($originalsource);  
    }
```

where current site is an array of the previous sites and the current site. I am looping through new sites each time with recursion in the larger program.

However, every time I run a `strcmp` on the current site and the new site, even when the urls are identical, I get a result of -1. Does anyone know why this might consistently be happening?

Thanks.

Comment: can you give us a sample code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the site you are testing contains something that makes it unique, like the current time or a hidden ID to save your session or something like this.

Anyway that will result in `strcmp` to not return 0. It would be bettor to have a function that gives you a percentage of equality so you can define a level above which you consider two sites as identical.

Answer (score 1):

> even when the urls are identical,

If the two input strings are identical, strcmp returns 0, so your input strings are not identical. Check the contents of $currentsite.

BTW `strcmp($a, $b) == 0` can be efficiently rewritten as `$a == $b`.

Comment: No - Strcmp($a, $b) is not the same as  $a == $b. The latter will do strange type changing. One good example is: '1e3' == '1000'. It is useful to use ==at times, but possibly not in conjunction with strings. I just noticed the original comment was 5 years ago, but it was wrong then, and it is wrong now :(.